# How to print the field of an array in JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects and I want to iterate it and print the field of the objects.

Example console log:

```
2:{id: "15", nombre: "Intrafungol", categoria: "Antifungicos", efecto: "Lucha 
contra la Tiña.", efecto_secundario: "Puede ocasionar hipersalivación, 
vómitos, diarrea y/o anorexia.", …}
```

So this is an example. I want to print the name of all medicines. And my code is not working

```
 function process_data(medicines) {

     for(var medicine in medicines ) {
       console.log(medicine["name"]);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do u hav a working demo? Codepen or jsFiddle?

Comment: nope.. because I'm using ajax

Comment: is it array or object? if it's object.. you have to add `Object.keys(medicines)` in your `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (i in array)` gives you the indices (enumerable properties), not the items in the array.

Your example would work if you change it to something like:

```
for (var medicine in medicines ) {
    console.log(medicines[medicine].nombre);
}
```

But if you are able to use `array.forEach()` that is great because you get the item in each callback of the function, and don't have to handle the index at all:

```
medicines.forEach(function (medicine) {
    console.log(medicine.nombre);
});
```

See more: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

That one won't work because on the medicine object there is no property `name`. Maybe you where refering to `nombre` you can try replacing the property and see if it works like this:

```
 function process_data(medicines) {
     for(var medicine in medicines ) {
       console.log(medicine["nombre"]);
```

you can also use the `forEach` array method

```
function process_data(medicines) {
    medicines.forEach(medicine => console.log(medicine.nombre);
}
```

Comment: yes i know, I changed the name, but I mean, I cant print "nombre"

Comment: can you provide an array with at least 2 elements ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do this:

```
function process_data(medicines) {


var html = "";
medicines.forEach(medicine => console.log(medicine.nombre));


 for(var medicine in medicines ) {



    html += "<div class='card mb-2 col-3 card-medicines'>"
            + "<a data-toggle='modal' href='#modall' style='width: 40%'><img class='card-img-top' src='" + medicine['url'] + "'></a>"
            + "<div class='card-block'>"
            + "<h4 class='card-title'>"
            + medicine.nombre
            +"</h4>"
```

And I can't print medicine['url] and medicine.nombre

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use `for` loop with arrays:

`for (var i=0; i<medicines.length; i++) {
    console.log(medicines[i].nombre);
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest implementation written in ES6:

```
const processData = medicines => medicines.forEach(med => {
  document
   .querySelector('.card')
   .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<h4>${med.nombre}</h4>`);
})
```

Check it out on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2hLja76/)